# Error with native base "Module `color` does not exist in the Haste module map"

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have an issue with native base on app start, both iOS or Android

```
error:(Unable to resolve module `color` from `#appRoot/native-base-theme/variables/platform.js`: Module `color` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

**What I already tried**

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`. (null))
5. Remove Pods and podfile.lock then pod install
6. Uninstall app on simulator and device.
7. Clean build folder on xcode
8. Restart MAC !

**Version**

```
native-base: "2.13.5"
react": "16.8.3"
react-moment": "0.9.2"
```

**Update**

This error occurred only on debug mode

Comment: I believe there are problems with the installation only.  Did you try re-installing `native-base` ?

Comment: @DipanshKhandelwal Yes I tried that without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
What I did is :
 - remove package-lock.json
 - npm start -- --reset-cache

If I only do npm start -- --reset-cache, it won't work... very weird.